# In javascript, Find an item in an array that contains a string and then return that item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings.

I want to search in that array for and string that contains a specific string.

If it's found, return that string WITHOUT the bit of the string we looked for.

So, the array has three words. "Strawbery", "Lime", "Word:Word Word"

I want to search in that array and find the full string that has "Word:" in it and return "Word Word"

So far I've tried several different solutions to no avail. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes looks promising, but I'm lost. Any suggestions?

Here's what I've been trying so far:

```
var arrayName = ['Strawberry', 'Lime', 'Word: Word Word']
function arrayContains('Word:', arrayName) {
    return (arrayName.indexOf('Word:') > -1);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you tried so far?

Comment: How about using `filter` with `includes` to select elements that contain your word and then `map` with `replace` to remove the word?

Comment: removes the first instance of the word? if the string was "aaaWord:bbbWord:ccc" would it return "aaabbbWord:ccc" or "aaabbbccc"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to search the array. And use `replace` to remove the word.

This code will return the value of the first element only.

```js
let arr = ["Strawbery", "Lime", "Word:Word Word"];
let search = "Word:";

let result = (arr.find(e => e.includes(search)) || "").replace(search, '');

console.log(result);
```

If there are multiple search results, you can use `filter` and `map`

```js
let arr = ["Strawbery", "Word:Lime", "Word:Word Word"];
let search = "Word:";

let result = arr.filter(e => e.includes(search)).map(e => e.replace(search, ''));

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **.map**:

```
words_array = ["Strawbery", "Lime", "Word:Word Word"]


function get_word(words_array, search_word) {
  res = '';
  words_array.map(function(word) {
  if(word.includes(search_word)) {
  res = word.replace(search_word, '')
  }
  })
  return(res)
  }
```

**Usage**:

```
res = get_word(words_array, 'Word:')

alert(res) // returns "Word Word"
```